# Efficient Way to Concat Strings

Tags: java, string, performance, concatenation, stringbuilder

In my app, I have to concatenate one String (~50chars) to another String (~5000chars). After this has occured, I am removing the first line (~50chars) of the big String.

As I am continuously receiving data, I have to be able to append and remove those lines very efficiently. I have already tried three possibilities, but these have been too slow:

(The 50chars String is `dataString` and the 5000chars String is `dataStringTot`.)

**Normal String Addition:**

```
dataStringTot = dataStringTot + "\n" + dataString; // Concatenate both strings
dataStringTot = dataStringTot.substring(dataStringTot.indexOf("\n") + 1); // Remove first line
```

**String Concat:**

```
dataStringTot = dataStringTot.concat("\n").concat(dataString); // Concatenate both strings
dataStringTot = dataStringTot.substring(dataStringTot.indexOf("\n") + 1); // Remove first line
```

**StringBuilder:**

Initializing the StringBuilder once:

```
dataStringTot = new StringBuilder(dataString);
```

Editing its contents:

```
dataStringTot.append("\n").append(dataString); // Concatenate both strings
dataStringTot.delete(0,dataStringTot.indexOf("\n") + 1); // Remove first line
```

**Result:**

The `StringBuilder` was the most efficient way of these three, but it is still too slow (I am missing data from the Internet, because the app needs too much time to process the string).

Is there any more efficient way to perform this task?

Comment: Could you use a List of lines?

Comment: you mean an ArrayList?   Edit: at the end I need to have a String

Comment: I think using a single String is the wrong design. What are your inputs and expected processing and output?

Comment: What do you mean by *it is still too slow*? I have concatenated 20000k Strings in less than a second using `StringBuilder`. Provide the relevant code to replicate your problem and check your performance issues.

Comment: I am developing an Android App, and I have to fill a TextView with my 5000chars String. Would there be a better approach than Strings?

Comment: 5000 chars only? This means you have a bigger problem here. Please provide the relevant code to help you, I'm sure you're missing something that can speed it up.

Comment: if you want to remove the String, why even append it? Can you do with three strings s1(50 chars) , s2(5000 chars) , s3 (5050 chars), avoid the last remove? as you have all Strings needed.

Comment: no, the thing is that its kind of a "Terminal window", where a new dataString gets appended on the bottom and the oldest line (the top one) gets removed. And I am sure that the concatenating of the string is slowing my app down, because if I comment the concatenating out, I dont miss any Internet data anymore.

Comment: Are you sure that the concatenation is the problem and it's not something the TextView is doing?

Comment: For the TextView, which displays the 5000chars String, I am using: `myTextView.setText(dataStringTot)`, and this happens about 30 times a second. I just tried it out with a 100'000chars String, and I was missing even more Inet data. Could the TextView be the problem (perhaps I shouldn't set such a large String in a TextView)?